# string handling

Tags: c#

I would like to know that if I have an english dictionary in a text file what is the best way to check whether a given string is a proper and correct english word. My dictionary contains about 100000 english words and I have to check on an average of 60000 words in one go. I am just looking for the most efficient way. Also should I store all the strings first or I just process them as they are generated.

Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100k is not too great a number, so you can just pop everything in a `Hashset<string>`.

Hashset lookup is key-based, so it will be lightning fast.

example how this might look in code is:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyDictionary.txt");
HashSet<string> myDictionary = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
  myDictionary.Add(line);
}

string word = "aadvark";
if (myDictionary.Contains(word))
{
  Console.WriteLine("There is an aadvark");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("The aadvark is a lie");
}
```

Comment: Edited to response to say Hashset instead of dictionary, misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher.

Just load the dictionary of valid words into a `HashSet<string>` and then either use `Contains` on each candidate string, or use some of the set operators to find all words which aren't valid.

For example:

```
// There are loads of ways of loading words from a file, of course
var valid = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines("dictionary.txt"));
var candidates = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines("candidate.txt"));

var validCandidates = candidates.Intersect(valid);
var invalidCandidates = candidates.Except(valid);
```

You may also wish to use case-insensitive comparisons or something similar - use the `StringComparer` static properties to get at appropriate instances of `StringComparer` which you can pass to the `HashSet` constructor.

If you're using .NET 2, you can use a `Dictionary<string, whatever>` as a poor-man's set - basically use whatever you like as the value, and just check for keys.